# Javascript targeting specific element and removing characters from it

Tags: javascript

I have a really complicated looking path that I want to target
first of all I don't what to use to get the path so javascript can target it, I have

1. Selector
2. Js Path
3. Xpath
4. Full Xpath

Then I want to remove a text from it, namely the word 'by'

Here's the code I frankenstiened together from all the things said by many other users:

```
$('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/section/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div');
{
$(this).html( $(this).html().replace("by",""); 
});
```

If you don't understand the code I tried to make, I first of all:

1. tried to target a path with Xpath and put it as a variable
2. I used this.html to target it (no idea why i used 2 but that's what one of the answers from this site)
3. Used .replace to attempt to replace the words "by Mishaal; Masked Man"

This did not work and gave me the error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9715G.png)

Help appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I think you have misplaced ")" in last line, it should be should be placed on third line before ";"

Answer (score 0):

The example is not very clearly explained, I also don't know what specifically other users advised, the specific case is missing but from guesses I can deduce that you are using jquery.
Try to pull xpath to a variable but not as a jquery object `$(...)` but as a regular string and only use `.replace()` on it.

```
const path = '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/section/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div';

const formatted = path.replace('be', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much everyone, I frankensteined everything I saw on webpages and concluded with this:

```
var element = document.evaluate( '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/section/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div' ,document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null ).singleNodeValue;

  element.textContent = element.textContent.replace('by ','')
```

it looks messy but it works.

Comment: the tutorial i followed: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-typeerror-substring-is-not-a-function